# Angular component won't display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-component, angular-directive, angular-components

I have piece of html I want to show as a component, as I'm not manipulating the DOM.

As a directive it works fine, but as a component it doesn't. I have made components before with no problem, just can't see what the issue is here.
If I comment in the component code, and the directive out, it doesn't work.

Any idea what I've done wrong?

```
(function() {
"use strict";

angular
    .module('x.y.z')


    // .component('triangularStatus', {
    //     bindings: {
    //         value: '=',
    //         dimension: '=?'
    //     },
    //     templateUrl: '/path/to/triangular-status.html',
    //     controller: TriangularStatusController,
    //     controllerAs: 'vm'
    // });


    .directive('triangularStatus', triangularStatus);

    function triangularStatus() {
        var directive = {
            scope: {
                value: '=',
                dimension: '=?'
            },
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: '/path/to/triangular-status.html',
            controller: TriangularStatusController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        };
        return directive;
    }



    TriangularStatusController.$inject = [];
    function TriangularStatusController() {
        var vm = this;
    }
})();
```

Comment: just want to point out that `replace` is not a valid component option (and deprecated for directives)

Comment: any errors in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: it would be nice if you provide a fiddle for us

Comment: I made a fiddle: https://codepen.io/bental/pen/XjKRwE but annoyingly it works there

Comment: The main difference between a component and a directive (as far as ng1 is concerned) is that a component is an opinionated directive. One of the things that a component is opinionated about is the name of the controller. By default a component will set controllerAs to be '$ctrl'. It probably isnt going to help you with your answer much, but I would recommend keeping it as $ctrl unless you have a good reason to change it

Comment: Fair enough, was just following John Papa's guidelines: https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

Comment: Ah yeah. Before we had components, directives needed to use controllerAs explicitly, as John Papa mentions. Otherwise you didnt have any direct reference to the controller, and had to add things to $scope. Components essentially made this the default behaviour. All components use controllerAs, and the controller is labelled $ctrl

Comment: can you please check `bindToController` part, I dont see that. So your values are not transferred to `vm` from `scope`. this might cause the issue

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working code, most probably you are not using vm.values to access data.

Just be sure you are using right version of angular js ~1.5

```js
(function(angular) {
angular.module('x.y.z', [])
    .component('triangularStatus', {
        bindings: {
            value: '=',
            dimensions:'=?'
        },
         template: '{{vm.value}} <br/> {{vm.dimensions}}' ,
        controller: TriangularStatusController,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
     });
   TriangularStatusController.$inject = [];
    function TriangularStatusController() {
       
    }
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "x.y.z"> 
<triangular-status  value="24" dimensions="348"></triangular-status>
</div>
```

Comment: It's true this is working, but it's not the answer to the issue I was facing, as you can see I was using vm in the directive and that was fine, so it wasn't that, and my angular is > v1.5.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of your component, using `bindings`, is not directly equivalent to the definition of your directive, using `scope`, even though both are defined to use `controllerAs`. This is because your component will be binding directly to the controller, and your directive will be binding to `$scope` (by default).

I've used your code in the snippet below, slightly modified to allow the component and directive(s) to be used together. I've also added an additional directive that makes use of [`bindToController:true`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) to demonstrate a directive that behaves a little more like a component in binding its attribute values directly to the controller, rather than to `$scope`.

I've also used a very basic shared template that attempts to show the bound attribute values by looking for them on `$scope`, followed by looking for them on `vm` (the ControllerAs).

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var templateBody = '<h2>$scope</h2>' +
    '<p>value: {{value}}</p><p>dimension: {{dimension}}</p>' +
    '<h2>vm</h2>' +
    '<p>vm.value: {{vm.value}}</p><p>vm.dimension: {{vm.dimension}}</p>';

  angular
    .module('x.y.z', [])


  .component('triangularStatusComponent', {
    bindings: {
      value: '=',
      dimension: '=?'
    },
    template: '<div><h1>Triangular Status Component</h1>' + templateBody + '</div>',
    controller: TriangularStatusController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })


  .directive('triangularStatusDirective', triangularStatusDirective)
  .directive('triangularStatusDirectiveBound', triangularStatusDirectiveBound);

  function triangularStatusDirective() {
    var directive = {
      scope: {
        value: '=',
        dimension: '=?'
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<div><h1>Triangular Status Directive</h1>' + templateBody + '</div>',
      controller: TriangularStatusController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
    };
    return directive;
  }

  function triangularStatusDirectiveBound() {
    //https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-
    var directive = {
      scope: {
        value: '=',
        dimension: '=?'
      },
      bindToController: true,
      replace: true,
      template: '<div><h1>Triangular Status Directive Bound</h1>' + templateBody + '</div>',
      controller: TriangularStatusController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
    };
    return directive;
  }

  TriangularStatusController.$inject = [];

  function TriangularStatusController() {
    var vm = this;
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="x.y.z">
  <triangular-status-component value="'componentValue'" dimension="'componentDimension'">
  </triangular-status-component>
  <hr>
  <triangular-status-directive value="'directiveValue'" dimension="'directiveDimension'">
  </triangular-status-directive>
  <hr>
  <triangular-status-directive-bound value="'directiveValueBound'" dimension="'directiveDimensionBound'">
  </triangular-status-directive-bound>
</div>
```

If you're finding that your code works as a directive, where your values are bound to `$scope`, but not as a component, where your values are bound to the controller, I would assume either your template html (most likely?) or your controller function are relying on trying to access your values as though they were on `$scope`. To confirm this, you may notice there are errors being logged to your javascript console that will help you zero in.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem is, that your missing the brackets:
angular.module('x.y.z')
change to 
angular.module('x.y.z', [])

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

As was mentioned in the comment, I need to clarify, the problem can be how are your JS files ordered or bundled, some other JS file executed later can overwrite this module and therefor you will not see any tag rendered.

Comment: If he is just asking for the module to use it, that wouldn't be the case. I think he declared the module in a separate file.

Comment: it depends on the order of execution, if it is as you said, it can be overwritten by the other file and therefor you would not see the component rendered. Thanks for the comment, I should mention it in the answer :)

Comment: You are totally right about the order of execution, then we should ask OP to make sure he is loading the module first and then the component.

Comment: This was not the case, given that the directive code worked when that was commented in I thought it was obvious, apologies, thanks though